# Rails Uninitialized constant routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I know this question is plastered on the net, but after looking at all the answers, i still can't figure out what my problem is.

Here's my route:

```
resources :applications do 
  resources :applicants do
    collection {put '/archived'}
    collection {put '/not_archived'}
  end
end
```

I then have a table at this path: `/applications/1/applicants` which calls my index method.

In this table listing all the applicants, i have a checkbox for each row and when they check the box, i want to set the "archived" flag in the db for that row using ajax.

Here's my ajax call:

```
$('.archive').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "PUT",
            url: '/applications/<%= @application.id %>/applicants/archived',
            data: {id: $(this).attr('id'), archived: true}
        });
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            type: "PUT",
            url: '/applications/<%= @application.id %>/applicants/not_archived',
            data: {id: $(this).attr('id'), archived: false}
        });
    }
});
```

But everytime i check a checkbox i get this error:

```
Started PUT "/applications/1/applicants/archived" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-03 00:07:20 -0500

ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Applications):
  activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `block in constantize'
  activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in `each'
  activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in `constantize'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:69:in `controller_reference'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:54:in `controller'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
  warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.6) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:473:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__281193607366851886__call__1094349027316042218__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.0.1) lib/quiet_assets.rb:20:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
  railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  webrick (1.3.1) lib/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  webrick (1.3.1) lib/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  webrick (1.3.1) lib/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

My ApplicantsController has these methods:

```
# PUT /applicants/archived/1
  def archived
    p 'here?'
    @applicant = Applicant.find(params[:id])
    @applicant.archived = params[:archived]
    #@application = current_company.applications.find(params[:application_id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @applicant.save
        format.js 
        #format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully updated.' }
        #format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "index" }
        format.json { render json: @applicant.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /applicants/not_archived/1
  def not_archived
    @applicant = Applicant.find(params[:id])
    @applicant.archived = params[:archived]
    #@application = current_company.applications.find(params[:application_id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @applicant.save
        format.js
        #format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully updated.' }
        #format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "index" }
        format.json { render json: @applicant.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Here's my rake routes output for these routes:

```
        archived_application_applicants PUT    /applications/:application_id/applicants/archived(.:format)                            applications/:application_id/applicants#archived
    not_archived_application_applicants PUT    /applications/:application_id/applicants/not_archived(.:format)                        applications/:application_id/applicants#not_archived
                 application_applicants GET    /applications/:application_id/applicants(.:format)                                     applicants#index
                                        POST   /applications/:application_id/applicants(.:format)                                     applicants#create
              new_application_applicant GET    /applications/:application_id/applicants/new(.:format)                                 applicants#new
             edit_application_applicant GET    /applications/:application_id/applicants/:id/edit(.:format)                            applicants#edit
                  application_applicant GET    /applications/:application_id/applicants/:id(.:format)                                 applicants#show
                                        PUT    /applications/:application_id/applicants/:id(.:format)                                 applicants#update
                                        DELETE /applications/:application_id/applicants/:id(.:format)                                 applicants#destroy
```

What is causing my error? I'm totally stumped.

Comment: In your controller PUT /applicants/archived/1, it seems you need to create archived as a member route not collection. Then accodingly you need to pass the id from your ajax call. And also you need to reconfigure your ajax paths.

Comment: are you using one controller for both applications and applicants ? or are there 2 controllers ? where are they placed ? looks like a namespace issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made a demo application replicating your context and it works fine for me. You can check it out here: https://github.com/Chipairon/so_applicants_route

I have cleaned the noise around the issue with the hope it serves you as a starting point.

I don't have enough reputation to comment your question, so I will put it here :)

I think the problem has to be in your `app/views/applicants/archived.js.erb` since you say the problem occurs when you check a checkbox. Could you post the content of that file?

On a side note, I'd like you to consider making the 'archived' action a member action. You are doing really an action over a single applicant, not over all the applicants:

```
resources :applications do
  resources :applicants do
    put :archived, on: :member
    put :not_archived, on: :member
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I hope this code will work for you:

```
$('.archive').on('click', function() {                                                      

if ($(this).is(':checked')){
    $.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: '<%= archived_application_applicants_path(@application.id) %>',
        data: {id: $(this).attr('id'), archived: true}
    });
}else {
    $.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: '<%= not_archived_application_applicants_path(@application.id) %>',
        data: {id: $(this).attr('id'), archived: false}
    });
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.archive').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')){
      $.ajax({
            type: "PUT",
            url: '<%= archived_application_applicants_path(:application_id => @application.id) %>',
            data: {id: $(this).attr('id'), archived: true}
    });
    }else {
     $.ajax({
            type: "PUT",
            url: '<%= not_archived_application_applicants_path(:application_id => @application.id) %>',
            data: {id: $(this).attr('id'), archived: true}
    });
    }

});
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It's actually the same path as i'm passing manually, but i still tried it and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This probably has nothing to do with your javascript. The router can't find the right set of modules/classes to resolve which controller to send the request to.

My guess is that your ApplicantsController is namespaced like so:

```
class Applications::ApplicantsController < Superclass;
end
```

But applicants_controller.rb is not in app/controllers/applications, which it would need to be to make Rails automagically create the Applications module. Move applicants_controller.rb or remove the namespacing, and things should fix themselves.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. Here's my controller declarations:`class ApplicationsController < ApplicationController` and `class ApplicantsController < ApplicationController`

Comment: But you are namespacing the Applicants controller in your routes.rb file, so you need to match that in your code. Change Applicants to be "class Applications::ApplicantsController < ApplicationController" and move it to app/controllers/applications/applicants_controller.rb and see if that works

Comment: And for a bit of unsolicited advice, I'd change the name of Applications in your data model. It's too easy for a typo of ApplicationsController vs. ApplicationController to really ruin your day.

Comment: So how does all my other code work (non ajax stuff) for the applications/applications stuff without having to change my namespace stuff? I mean if you go to `/applications/1/applicants` it shows a list of applicants, and if you go to `/applications/1/applicants/1` it shows the data for that applicant etc.